# Moving of series in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have [jsFiddle examle](http://jsfiddle.net/VXTeR/7/) where it's possible to move series by dragging of yellow line. If you will press mouse button in front of some tick in the bottom of the graphic and move it to the top, you will see that mouse is not in front of that tick any more. What I want to know is how to make series and ticks exactly follow the mouse.

Also in this code i use `.update({min: ,max: });` but it doesn't work in Visual Studio. How can I make it work? I can't use `.setExtremes(min,max);` because it makes my application terribly slow.

Many thanks in advance for any ideas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/VXTeR/10/

Fixed step function:

```
var step = function(e) {
    line.translate(-40, e.pageY - clickY);

    var y1 = grafico.toValue(clickY),
        y2 = grafico.toValue(e.pageY);

    move = y1 - y2;

    grafico.setExtremes(-100 + move, 400 + move, true, false)
}
```